# Chromium Default --audio-buffer-size=2048

Tags: chromium

In short I've done a fresh install of Ubuntu and as expected I've encountered the same audio issues I had originally. I backed up my sources for the fixes except for one: crackling sounds within Chromium.

I solved this last time by changing the audio buffer size but cannot figure it out this time round. This fix works perfectly for me if I run 'chromium-browser --audio-buffer-size=2048' in the terminal.

How can I make this permanent? I recall changing a default file somewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command `gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop`

Scroll down to the line:

`Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser`

And change to

`Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --audio-buffer-size=2048`

This will work whenever you click on Chromium on the launcher or your chosen dock (e.g. Docky)

Comment: Or potentially in here `/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications` in a flatpak stylee.